# how to get the objects embedded in excel usng C#

Tags: c#, excel, object, embedded-resource, packaging

I have an application where I need to get the objects that are embedded in excel should be stored in some location through code.

```
                        connection.Close();
                        //connection.ResetState();
                        string embeddingPartString;
                        //ArrayList chkdLstEmbeddedFiles = new ArrayList(); ;
                        List<String> chkdLstEmbeddedFiles = new List<string>();
                        //string fileName = txtSourceFile.Text;
                        if (filepath == string.Empty || !System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        // Open the package file 
                        pkg = Package.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath);

                        string extension = fi.Extension.ToLower();

                        if ((extension == ".docx") || (extension == ".dotx") || (extension == ".docm") || (extension == ".dotm"))
                        {
                            embeddingPartString = "/word/embeddings/";
                        }
                        else if ((extension == ".xlsx") || (extension == ".xlsm") || (extension == ".xltx") || (extension == ".xltm"))
                        {
                            embeddingPartString = "/xl/embeddings/";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            embeddingPartString = "/ppt/embeddings/";
                        }

                        // Get the embedded files names. 
                        foreach (PackagePart pkgPart in pkg.GetParts())
                        {
                            if (pkgPart.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(embeddingPartString))
                            {
                                string fileName1 = pkgPart.Uri.ToString().Remove(0, embeddingPartString.Length);
                                chkdLstEmbeddedFiles.Add(fileName1);
                            }
                        }
                        //pkg.Close();
                        if (chkdLstEmbeddedFiles.Count == 0)
                            //MessageBox.Show("The file does not contain any embedded files."); 

                            // Open the package and loop through parts  
                            // Check if the part uri to find if it contains the selected items in checked list box 
                            pkg = Package.Open(filepath);
                        foreach (PackagePart pkgPart in pkg.GetParts())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < chkdLstEmbeddedFiles.Count; i++)
                            {
                                object chkditem = chkdLstEmbeddedFiles[i];

                                if (pkgPart.Uri.ToString().Contains(embeddingPartString + chkdLstEmbeddedFiles[i].ToString()))
                                {
                                    // Get the file name 
                                    string fileName1 = pkgPart.Uri.ToString().Remove(0, embeddingPartString.Length);

                                    // Get the stream from the part 
                                    System.IO.Stream partStream = pkgPart.GetStream();
                                    //string filePath = txtDestinationFolder.Text + "\\" + fileName1;

                                    // Write the steam to the file. 
                                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile");
                                    System.IO.FileStream writeStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\jyshet\Documents\MicrosoftDoc_File.docx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                                    ReadWriteStream(pkgPart.GetStream(), writeStream);

                                    // If the file is a structured storage file stored as a oleObjectXX.bin file 
                                    // Use Ole10Native class to extract the contents inside it. 
                                    if (fileName1.Contains("oleObject"))
                                    {
                                        // The Ole10Native class is defined in Ole10Native.cs file 
                                        // Ole10Native.ExtractFile(filePath, txtDestinationFolder.Text);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        pkg.Close();
```

I am able to download only doc file and rest are not seen like txt and mht files. Please suggest what to do in this case. My problem is any objects embedded in excel should be downloaded thru code and saved in destination.